# How to get an index of files listed by os.scandir()?

Tags: python, file, indexing, scandir

I am using os.scandir to get a list a files in a given directory. It works fine by returning the files names. I am wondering if there is a way to point to a file list generated by scandir. In fact I am looking for a index like listbox so you can process a choice made by a user. Thanks for any help. The code I have is like this:

```
def listFiles():
dir_entries = scandir(instaPath)
for entry in dir_entries:
    if entry.is_file():
        info = entry.stat()
        print(entry.name)
        # print(entry.index ?)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. `enumerate` can be used to map a list to pairs of index, member.

Comment: Thanks for your answer tripleee. Sorry I was not clear. I just want to display the list of files from a directory. With the list, a sequential number for each entry, so instead of typing a file name, I would like to select the file by a number.  1 - test.txt    2 - another.txt  and so on.

Comment: If you are seeking help for a particular GUI programming framework, you need to [edit] your question to clarify which one. If this is not for a GUI, what exactly do you mean by a listbox? `dir[13]` fetches the 14th (!) item from a list variable `dir`.

Comment: `enumerate()` will do what you want. `for index, entry in enumerate(dir_entries, 1):`